# Gulpfile, Rsync,RsyncWrapper, Rsync Exits with code 12

Tags: vagrant, gulp, rsync

Im trying to use gulp to handle my rysnc task from a local dev environment to a running vagrant machine.

The gulp task is set up like this:

```
var rsync        = require('rsyncwrapper').rsync;
var secrets      = require('./secrets.json');

// ###Rsync
// Ran from gulp
gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  rsync({
    ssh: true,
    src: './website/',
    dest: secrets.servers.dev.rsyncDest,
    recursive: true,
    syncDest: true,
    exclude: ['node_modules'],
    args: ['--verbose'],
    privateKey: './.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key',
    onStdout: function (data) { 
      console .log (data.toString ()); 
    } 
  },function (error,stdout,stderr,cmd) {
        if ( error ) {
            // failed
            console.log(error.message);
        } else {
            // success
            console.log("folder synced!");
        }
    });
});
```

The secrets.json contains the path to my destination vagrant machine:

```
{
  "servers": {
    "dev": {
      "rsyncDest": "vagrant@192.168.2.101:/opt/webiste"
    }
  }
}
```

The rest of my gulp file works without issue, a normal vagrant rsync also works to transfer the file across.

However, when I run my task deploy, I simply get: Rsync Exited with code 12.

After some googling I found that this means the protocol stream has failed but I am unsure as even where to begin trying to fix this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.  It occurred when I destroyed and rebuilt my vagrant machine, but I left the old key in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. The error message gulp-rsync isn't helpful. If you try to login directly you'll get an error like this:

```
>> ssh vagrant@192.168.50.104
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
87:9b:39:02:b8:96:6b:21:01:fa:b5:42:5f:0a:0b:f7.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/me/.ssh/known_hosts:36
RSA host key for 192.168.50.104 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

To fix it, edit the file `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Remove the line for the host key of your vagrant machine. In my case, it was line beginning with 192.158.50.104.

The next time you run gulp-rsync, you'll have to type `yes` at the prompt.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and solve my issue.